# ValueError: `sequences` must be a list of iterables. Found non-iterable: 0.0382184

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, librosa

I am extracting Mel spectrogram from the audio file then I want to apply padding

```
y,sr = librosa.load(r"/content/test.WAV")
mel = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr)
mel=np.mean(mel, axis=0)
mel=tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(mel,maxlen=1500)
```

but I am receiving **TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float32' has no len()During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:**
**ValueError: sequences must be a list of iterables. Found non-iterable: 0.0382184**
I tried changing `mel=tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(list(mel),maxlen=1500)`
and it didn't work there are 2 or 3 questions on StackOverflow similar to my questions none of them helped me so please don't bother to suggest them

Comment: no, the mel=np.mean(Mel, axis=0)doesn't return a single float it returns a NumPy array of shape (4280,)

Comment: Read the error message, it says that sequences must be a list of iterables, a  numpy array (4280,) is not a list of iterables, a 2D list would be.

Comment: so what is the solution I am using this for inference so I can only provide 1 list  when I used the padding for 1300 list in training it worked

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out  you have to do some reshaping

```
mel=mel.reshape(1,mel.shape[0])
```